# OCaml exception raise for division

Tags: exception, ocaml

I have a simple program like so:

```
 let dividebyfour (a: int) : int = 
   a/4;;
```

But I want to check if a is a multiple of 4 (like 4, 8, 12, 16, etc.) and if it is not a multiple I would like to raise an exception, something like "not a multiple of 4". How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on a fact that all divisible by four numbers has two lower bits set to zero. So the formulae is:

```
let divisible_by_4 x = x land 3 = 0
```

Here, I've just tested that both lower bits aren't set to 1.

Moreover, modular division is rather heavy operation, so if you can do some task without it, then do.

And since, you would like to raise an exception, when the number is not divisible, it is good to use assert of some kind:

```
assert (divisible_by_4 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let dividebyfour a = 
           if a mod 4 =0 then true else false;;
```

It 'a function that returns a boolean and use the mod function

Comment: No need for `if`, just `let divisible_by_four x = x mod 4 = 0`.

Comment: I put the if statement to better explain the concept and the possibility of use as the question seems to me to beginners.You could put your answer instead of putting a useless comment

Answer (score 0):

You can define an exception like this:

```
exception Not_multiple_of_4
```

You can raise this exception like this:

```
raise Not_multiple_of_4
```

If you want to get fancy you can include the offending value in the exception:

```
exception Not_multiple_of_4 of int
```

Then you can pass along the bad value:

```
raise (Not_multiple_of_4 a)
```